# How can I group elements with \right in table?

Tags: tables

Let's say I have a simple table defined like this:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}||p{5cm}| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table} \\
 \hline
 Part Num & Part Let \\
 \hline
 1 & A\\
 2 & B\\
 3 & C \\
 4 & D\\
 5 & E\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Now, I want to group certain elements with something like this:

[image]

but brace on the right side. Let's say I want to group `1` and `2`, `3` alone and then again `4` and `5`, and I want to write some text next to them. How can I do this in tables?

Comment: Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official Stack Exchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: Ctrl+G). This ensures that all images will always be accessible and won't expire.

Comment: @samcarter Sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your part numbers are single-line-height entities, then this introduction of `\tablegroup{<stacked-content>}{<comment>}` might suffice.

Note that I use the `/` character as a row separator in the stacks, but this can be changed in the preamble.

EDITED to respond to OP comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\setstackEOL{/}% DEFINES ROW SEPARATOR IN STACK
\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}
\newcommand\tablegroup[2]{%
  \addstackgap{\scaleleftright[1ex]{.}{\Centerstack{#1}}{\}}~\parbox[c]{1.5in}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l||p{5cm}| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table} \\
 \hline
 Part Num & Part Let \\
 \hline
 \tablegroup{1/2/3}{text about it} & \Centerstack{A/B/C}\\
 \tablegroup{4/5}{lots and lots and lots and lots and 
   lots and more text about it} & \Centerstack{D/E}\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @pixel I just revised it, based on your earlier [deleted] comment.  Is this version preferable to the original.  If not, I will undo this version of the answer.

Comment: Yes, this version is actually preferable. But, I noticed that in the earlier version if I just type text next to the group it works. But, this is more elegant. Thanks once more.